# In Perl, how do you access an element from a hash of hashes

Tags: perl

in this example I want to read the letter "d" from `$ref`:

```
$ref={a,b,c,{d,e}}
```

Comment: is this valid perl? Maybe you should start with [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-tutorials.html) with the tutorials. Moreover, what have you tried?

Comment: It is valid perl, kinda. It means the same as `my $ref = { a => "b", c => { d => "e" } }` and won't work in Strict mode.

Answer (score 4):

```
# Start using these!
use strict;
use warnings;

# A more standard way of writing your example.
my $ref = { a => "b", c => { d => "e", f => "g" } };

# How to access elements within the structure.
my $inner = $ref->{c};
print $_, "\n" for
    $inner->{d},   # e
    keys %$inner,  # d f
    $ref->{c}{d},  # e    (directly, without using intermediate variable).
;
```

For more info, see the [Perl Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

Answer (score 2):

`print keys %{$ref->{c}};` will work for that specific (awful) example. It may or may not solve your problem since we don't know what the problem actually is.